# How to set shiny widget css on server side?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

My goal is to change actionButton css by every click, is there a way I can implement without using shinyBS and shinyjs?

Please see the minimal reproducible example below.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style("#action{color:black;}"),
    actionButton("action", label = "Action")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$action, {
      message(input$action %% 2)
      if (input$action %% 2) {
        tags$style("#action{color:red;}")
      } else {
        tags$style("#action{color:black;}")
      }
    })
  }
)
```

click 1 red

click 2 black

click 3 red

click 4 black

click 5 red

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript way:

```
js <- "
function changeColor(button){
  var currentColor = button.style.color;
  var newColor = currentColor === 'red' ? 'black' : 'red';
  button.style.color = newColor;
}
"

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  actionButton(
    "btn", "Click me", style = "color: red;", 
    onclick = "changeColor(this)"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: is there a way I can use hex code instead of color?